# Sort project browser tree view programmatically

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need to know how to set the order of elements shown in EA's project browser programmatically (in order to mimic the green arrows).

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and adjust your question

Answer (score 1):

The tree view can not be sorted freely. EA puts a couple of constraints on the sorting. So diagrams, packages and a couple of other elements appear always on top and in groups. This is hard coded.

Use `Element.TreePos` to change the order where appropriate to simulate a manual order.

FWIW: Features have another queer behavior sometimes. You might need to uncheck the following in Tools/Options:

[image]