# How to give descending order sort for a tree view item in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, sorting

I am using EA through C# addin, i have given

```
> // Summary:
>         //Sorts the items in System.Windows.Forms.TreeView control.
>          public void Sort();  -----(inbuilt Treeview metadata).
```

**

```
private void SortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.treeView_Control.Sort();
            }
```

**

now this is sorting the tree view items in Ascending order.

soon i complete sorting in ascending order, again when i click on the same sort option it should again arrange the tree view items into descending order.

Someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: How is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133835/sort-project-browser-tree-view-programmatically ? Had my assumption been wrong? Please review/edit/delete the related question.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN - `TreeView.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.sort(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This method reapplies the default sort, which is alphabetical by node text, or a custom sort specified by the [`TreeViewNodeSorter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.treeviewnodesorter(v=vs.110).aspx) property. You can use this method if the text of existing nodes is changed or nodes are moved by the user, and you want to sort the items again.

So you will need to create you `IComparer` and set the `TreeViewNodeSorter`

```
public class NodeSorter : IComparer
{
    public bool Descending {get;set;}

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        TreeNode tx = x as TreeNode;
        TreeNode ty = y as TreeNode;

        int result = // Your compare logic here

        if (Descending && result!=0) {
            result = 2 % result + 1;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Somehwere in you initilization (ctor maybe) add `this.treeView_Control.TreeViewNodeSorter = new NodeSorter()`
And then in your sorting event:

```
private void SortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sorter = (NodeSorter)this.treeView_Control.TreeViewNodeSorter;
    sorter.Descending = !sorter.Descending;
    this.treeView_Control.Sort();
}
```